# Data structure for searching strings

Tags: c#, string, search, tree

I am looking for the best data structure for the following case:
In my case I will have thousands of strings, however for this example I am gonna use two for obvious reasons. So let's say I have the strings "Water" and "Walter", what I need is when the letter "W" is entered both strings to be found, and when "Wat" is entered "Water" to be the only result. I did a research however I am still not quite sure which is the correct data structure for this case and I don't want to implement it if I am not sure as this will waste time. So basically what I am thinking right now is either "Trie" or "Suffix Tree". It seems that the "Trie" will do the trick but as I said I need to be sure. Additionally the implementation should not be a problem so I just need to know the correct structure. Also feel free to let me know if there is a better choice. As you can guess normal structures such as Dictionary/MultiDictionary would not work as that will be a memory killer. I am also planning to implement cache to limit the memory consumption. I am sorry there is no code but I hope I will get a answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to build some sort of auto-complete functionality.  I would look to see if there's something already existing that you could use rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Are you planning to use generics?

Comment: My case is a bit specific and I couldn't find anything that will do the trick. This explanation here is very shallow.

Comment: @GarryVass I guess I would have to at one point or another, but List<string> would not solve the whole case if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a Trie is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should user `Trie`.  Tries are the foundation for one of the fastest known sorting algorithms (burstsort), it is also used for spell checking, and is used in applications that use text completion. You can see details [here](http://counterhelix.com/2011/08/16/basic-trie-data-structure-implementation/).

Answer (score 1):

Practically, if you want to do auto suggest, then storing upto 3-4 chars should suffice.
I mean suggest as and when user types "a" or "ab" or "abc" and the moment he types "abcd" or more characters, you can use map.keys starting with "abcd" using c# language support lamda expressions.

Hence, I suggest, create a map like:
Map<char, <Map<char, Map<char, Set<string>>>>> map;
So, if user enters "a", you look for map[a] and finds all children.

Comment: This seems very unpractical and limiting, I will need to implement my own structure because it has to work with 3-4 classes (1 abstract).

Comment: Basically if you want to implement in an easy way, then you can use C# language provided constructs such as lamda expressions to filter the data based on your needs something like:<br> map.keys.select(k => {return k.startsWith("user_input");} <br>Not sure about exact syntax.

Comment: Lambda expressions are slow since they iterate the collection and I mentioned that I am going to have thousands of entries. Concerning your post => this way is a memory killer, image it with thousands of long strings, this was my first idea but after some calculations it revealed itself as very very bad idea.